# Is it possible to trigger Google Chrome browser translate function from Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Small intro to a problem: I'm looking for a way to translate pages in chrome with keyboard shortcut instead of mouse input. As far as I know there's no chrome extension that enables this.
I could make an extension for this task but I need to know beforehand:

Is it possible to call Google Chrome in-browser translate function from inside Chrome extension?
I can't find any API for translator, available keybinding extensions also don't offer this functionality.

By "in-browser translate function" I mean functionality in below screen:

[image: Chrome translate]

It's just a matter of keybindings, no internal translator modification should be used.

Answer (score 2):

I use this feature very often and use a functional-but-janky workaround which works on Windows.

When a page is loaded, press the 'menu' key on the keyboard (looks like ≣, usually next to right ctrl key, shift+F10 has same functionality), then T, then left/right to switch languages.

Doesn't work if focus is on a contextual object like a text area or image or whatever (as the menu key brings up the menu specific for that object).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I installed extension Linguist (not advertising), there is a hotkey in the settings to translate the entire page and back.

Link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linguist-web-pages-transl/gbefmodhlophhakmoecijeppjblibmie

It seems that the same Google Translate API is used, so the quality of the translation should be the same.